# Differences between "reboot" and "ec2-reboot-instances"

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

What are the differences, if any,  between invoking `reboot` on an EC2 instance's command line and issuing  the `ec2-reboot-instances` command from the AWS Command Line Tools on another machine?

Does `ec2-reboot-instances` do anything that sending `reboot` over an SSH session won't do, such as handling environmental things specific to AWS?

Is there a preference between the two commands?

In my specific case, I'm using the Java library to access the AWS API rather than the command line tool, but it still invokes the same command on AWS. The Java library is more verbose than the command line tool, so it would be easier to send the `reboot` command over SSH, but I'd like to understand if there are any other considerations that would make it worth using the AWS API approach.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Differences in use:

- No SSH access required (can be run from any computer, or even the AWS console)
- `ec2-reboot-instances` requires AWS credentials
- Can easily script for multiple instances (easier to integrate with other AWS services)

Difference in functionality:

- `ec2-reboot-instances` will force a hard reboot after 4 minutes if the instance hasn't cleanly shutdown. (See [Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-RebootInstances.html))
- The command does not confirm success - the reboot request is queued but you are not informed if it worked or if a hard start is required, etc (you are informed of outright failed commands - e.g. permissions problems, etc)
- There is a slight delay in execution of command - usually not noticable

In cases where the instance is responsive and can be accessed via SSH `reboot` (via SSH) will perform the same task as `ec2-reboot-instances`.

---

As an additional point of mention, reboots from SSH will suffice for scheduled maintenance (i.e. you do not need to use `ec2-reboot-instances`). As per the [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/maintenance-help/):

> Instance reboots are reboots of your virtual instance, and are
> equivalent to an operating system reboot.
>
> Managing your own instance reboots is very straightforward. ...you can
> also reboot your instance from the operating system of your instance.

Comment: Will a non-EC2 reboot command trigger scheduled maintenance events?

Comment: @ceejayoz: Yes it will - updated the answer to mention it.

Comment: I have a situation where issuing `sudo reboot` resets the attached EBS volume to the file system state as when the AMI was created...and restarting from the Console does not.  I wish I could provide more details...but yeah it's weird.